# Missing Exit Stamp on US passport upon leaving the Schengen area

Tags: schengen, passport-stamps, visa-free-entry

My boyfriend,who's a US citizen,(thus he's eligible for visa-free travel to EU) came to visit me, here in Italy, in September.
He stayed here for a total number of 86 days on the 90 days limit every 180. He got his passport stamped upon entry but not when he exited from Fiumicino,even though he asked that multiple times (but apparently there was no border guard,whatsoever). I forgot to say that he has had his passport scanned multiple times and he got a green ICTS sticker glued on the front page of his passport,with the date :15/12 (EU departure date).
Anyways,he's coming to visit me again in April and he got a bank statement which shows clearly that he got back to the US and has kept a copy of his electronic ticket (even though he no longer has the boarding passes). Has anyone else ever had the same problem and was able to enter the Schengen area,effortlessly, again?
Thanks for your help!
Regards
L.

Comment: Did he fly directly to the US from Fiumicino, or did he transit through another country in the Schengen Area? I find it quite surprising that there would not have been any exit passport control.

Comment: Yes he flew directly from Fiumicino and asked for a stamp multiple times but they just scanned his passport for a random security check and put an "ICTS" sticker on the front page of his passport ,with a 15/12 date (EU format)

Comment: The people who do security checks and put ICTS stickers on passports are the people whose job it is to ensure that air passengers don't bring weapons with them.  They have nothing to do with border control, and they can't give exit stamps.  He was asking the wrong people at the wrong time.

Comment: @phoog while they are definitely not exit border control agents, ICTS agents often have a mission to ensure passengers have the right documentation to enter the destination country and/or that they are not somehow dangerous or undesirable, rather than checking for weapons (that’s the job of the guys at the scanners/doing the pat downs, and those don’t usually add stickers to the passports). But you meet those at check-in and/or at the gate, while there should have been exit passport control and security somewhere in between.

Comment: Yeah @jcaron is right: there should have been exit passport control but there simply wasn't at this point

Comment: It sounded weird to me,too but I got told that,sometimes, in Fiumicino they would forget about stamping people's passport ,especially when leaving